# Different wallpapers in different OU's

Tags: active-directory, windows-server, gpo

I am trying to deploy different wallpapers (or different settings) in two different OU's.
I have completed alla the prerequisites for the shared folder etc etc.  (nothing)
I have linked seperately the gpo's to the OU i want to deploy the wallpaper. (nothing)
I tried via security filtering on every GPO. (nothing)
I also tried to block inheritance. (nothing)
I also tried to link all GPO's to the root of the forest (nothing)
**Please note that if i disable a link on the root of the forest, it works. but together in separate Ou's nothing is working.**
But i am stuck.
I have setup a windows server 2019 with AD DS role and DNS server. i have static IP on all my laptops and desktops.

Answer (score 1):

In my use case before we’re always Deploy Desktop Background Wallpaper using Group Policy for single OU only, and
We’re adding all computer’s to this OU, to applied the GPO wallpaper.

I suggest if you have a multiple OU’s, create a GPO wallpaper per OU, and also you can review this [document link](https://www.prajwaldesai.com/deploy-desktop-background-wallpaper-using-group-policy/)